# Textarea value not resetting in post action with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using PHP and Ajax to post without page refresh. Everything works fine but the textarea content is not reset after submitting the form.

This is my Ajax code:

```
  $("#new_post__add").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); 
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method");
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    
    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data : form_data
    }).done(function(response){ //
        $("#load_data").html(response);
    });
});
```

How can I reset the textarea value after successfully submitting the form? can you please edit my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the done callback, you can target the text area element and clear it.

`textarea.value = '';`

```
  $("#new_post__add").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); 
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method");
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    
    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data : form_data
    }).done(function(response){ //
        $("#load_data").html(response);
        $('#new_post__add textarea').val(""); //this is assuming there is only one textarea inside your form
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also reset all elements within the form by doing any of the following

```
$('#new_post__add').trigger('reset');
$('#new_post__add')[0].reset();
document.getElementById('#new_post__add').reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `success` instead of `done`. Depending on the version, `success` may or may not be deprecated.

```
  $("#new_post__add").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); 
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method");
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    
    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data : form_data
    }).success(function(response){ //
        $("#load_data").html(response);
    });
});
```

If it still doesn't work, I'd add `fail` and `always` handlers with `console.log` output to see what's happening. If you're sure `success` is not deprecated in your version, then the equivalent are `error` and `complete`. Or maybe I've mixed versions. Hell, you can have all six, and see which get called!